# Knockout.js - Updating an array in parent view model, with value in second view model

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

So I have 2 view models, one that houses an array I use that binds each data node in `dataList` to the form, and the other is used as a model for each data node.  I'm trying to update the array in the first viewmodel with the data from the second:

**HTML**:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:mainArray">
    <select data-bind="options: $root.ourTypes, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', value: $data.OurTypeId"></select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var dataList = [        
    { OurTypeId: 4 }, // there are other values here... 
    { OurTypeId: 2 }, // and here...
    { OurTypeId: 3 }  // and here...
];
var ourTypes = [
    { ID:"1", Name:"None", Limit:0 },
    { ID:"2", Name:"Fruits", Limit:5 },
    { ID:"3", Name:"Vegetables", Limit:5 },
    { ID:"4", Name:"Meats", Limit:2 }
];
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(dataList);
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

function MyViewModel(dataList) {
    var self = this;
    self.ourTypes = ourTypes;
    self.mainArray = ko.observableArray([]);

    if (dataList.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<dataList.length; i++) {
            var myDataViewModel = new MyDataViewModel(dataList[i]);
            //alert(myDataViewModel.OurType);
            self.mainArray.push(myDataViewModel);
        } 
    }
}

function MyDataViewModel(vm) {
    var self = this;
    if (vm != null) {                     
        var myType = "";
        for (var i=0; i<ourTypes.length; i++) {
            if (ourTypes[i].ID == vm.OurTypeId)
                myType = ourTypes[i].Name;
        }
        self.OurTypeId = ko.observable(vm.OurTypeId);
        self.OurType = myType;
   } else {
       self.OurTypeId = 0;    
       self.OurType = "";    
   }
   self.OurTypeId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       var updatedItem = 0;
       var newName = "";
       for (var i=0; i<ourTypes.length; i++) {
          if (ourTypes[i].ID == newValue) {
            self.OurType = ourTypes[i].Name;
            // alert(ourTypes[i].Name);
             updatedItem = i;
          }
       }
   //  I want to do something like this to update "OurType" in mainArray...
   //  var theList = MyViewModel.mainArray();
   //  theList[updatedItem].OurType = self.OurType;
   //  MyViewModel.mainArray(theList);
   });
}
```

This is actually a slimmed-down version of the code that just focuses on "ourTypes", my fiddle has a little more.  I use the ID on the dropdown to indicate a change in the model, but then I have to update the actual name of the type manually (you'll see how the name does not update when the ID does in my fiddle), so I attempt to do that in a `.subscribe()` function, but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/ks6nbzp7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name of `OurType` is supposed to change automatically when you change the ID, this is a good job for a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
self.OurType = ko.computed(function() {

    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ourTypes, function(type) {
        return type.ID == self.OurTypeId();
    }).Name;

});
```

When a computed observable runs, it takes note of all the other observables that are accessed — in our case here, that's just `self.OurTypeId()`. That's called a dependency. Whenever a dependency changes, the computed is automatically run again.

Here, we are using Knockout helper function `ko.utils.arrayFirst` to iterate over `ourTypes` and return the first element in it where the ID matches the `self.OurTypeId()` the user has selected. We then return the `.Name` of that `ourType` element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/ks6nbzp7/4/)

Please note that your `if (vm != null)` `else` clause is potentially trouble: the values you set there aren't observable.

```
self.OurTypeId = 0;
```

That means that `MyDataViewModel`s where `vm` is `null` will be broken - Knockout will bind the `<select>` to a plain, non-observable "0" and will never update again.

Also, one time you are making `self.SlotPosition` an observable, another time you are making it an observableArray.

It is better to initialize the properties as observable once and only update their values:

```
function MyDataViewModel(vm) {
    var self = this;

    this.SlotPosition = ko.observable();
    this.OurTypeId    = ko.observable();

    if (vm) {
        this.SlotPosition(vm.SlotPosition);
        this.OurTypeId(vm.OurTypeId);
    }

    this.OurType = ko.computed(function() {

        if (!self.OurTypeId()) {
            return;
        }

        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ourTypes, function(type) {
            return type.ID == self.OurTypeId();
        }).Name;

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - looks great! To address your other concerns, yeah, I probably should change that Id = 0 to Id = 1. Was more of just demonstrating I set some default values if I don't get any data.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Just to make sure there's no misunderstanding - the problem isn't that you set id to 0. The problem is that you didn't assign it an observable. So `id = 0` is problematic, while `id = ko.observable(0)` would have been fine. But the way it's structured above is better anyhow.